# Why is \setmainfont case sensitive with XelateX but not with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{tex Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If I compile it with `LuaLaTeX` all is fine.

But, if I compile it with `XeLaTeX` I get the error

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "tex Gyre Pagella" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.7 \setmainfont{tex Gyre Pagella}

?
```

This is because I've written `tex Gyre Pagella` instead of `TeX Gyre Pagella` in the argument of `\setmainfont`. If I change it to `TeX Gyre Pagella` then `XeLaTeX` compiles it.

Why this behavior? Do `LuaLaTeX` and `XeLaTeX` load different `fontspec` packages or there is something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Luaotfload normalizes all names supplied by the font.
Apart from lowercasing you can also leave out spaces
if you wish.

Comment: @phg Thanks for the comment. So it is engine-dependant, nothing to do with `fontspec`. Can you explain it more extensively in an answer (for example what is luaotfload), detailing the differences between `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`?

Comment: It is not engine-dependent, just how Luaotfload (and, incidentally, Context) treat things. The rationale is simple: Font names are a horrible mess that will haunt you and your descendants to the fifth generation if you attempt to uncover a system behind them. Since capitalization of identifiers can vary even within a font family, the only sane approach is to eliminate it completely. For info about Luaotfload read ``texdoc luaotfload`` and ``man 1 luaotfload-tool``.

Comment: @phg do you want to write an answer for this one?

Comment: @Paul Gessler I’ll see to it later, no time right now. Thanks for reminding, though.

Comment: @phg here's another friendly reminder. :-)

Comment: @Paul Gessler I’m unable to post answers due to the captcha barrier which fails to load, leaving me without any obvious way to prove my humanity to the robots of stackexchange. I guess that’s what you get for relying on a web forum …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CW from the comments:

> `luaotfload` normalizes all names supplied by the font. Apart from lowercasing you can also leave out spaces if you wish.

So, for XeLaTeX, spacing and casing are significant, while for LuaLaTeX, they are not.

> This is not engine-dependent, just how `luaotfload` (and, incidentally, ConTeXt) treat things. The rationale is simple: Font names are a horrible mess that will haunt you and your descendants to the fifth generation if you attempt to uncover a system behind them. Since capitalization of identifiers can vary even within a font family, the only sane approach is to eliminate it completely. For info about `luaotfload` read `texdoc luaotfload` and `man 1 luaotfload-tool`.